# C# Login Form, Login Button , security

Tags: c#, database, forms, security, authentication

So, I am new to VS and C#, I am self-teaching to get a better understanding of the back-end of the product I work with. I have created a small database with some information and a Login form. Everything appears to compile correctly but is that the security way to do that or there is another way,
any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tbladmin where username=@username and password=@password", sqlcon);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtusername.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtpassword.Text);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dtbl);


        try
        {

            if (dtbl.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                if (dtbl.Rows[0]["role"].ToString() == "Admin")
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select date from tbladmin where username=@username and password=@password", sqlcon);
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtusername.Text);
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtpassword.Text);
                    SqlDataAdapter sda2 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
                    DataTable dss = new DataTable();
                    sda2.Fill(dss);
                    String value2 = dss.Rows[0][0].ToString();
                    DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(dss.Rows[0][0].ToString());
                    Class1.Txtusername = txtusername.Text;
                    Debug.WriteLine("value is :   " + value2);

                    if (date.AddDays(90) < DateTime.Now)
                    {
                        Changpassad obj2 = new Changpassad();
                        this.Hide();
                        obj2.Show();
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        calladmin obj = new calladmin(dss.Rows[0][0].ToString());
                        this.Hide();
                        obj.Show();
                    }
                }
            }
            else if (dtbl.Rows.Count == 0)
            {
                SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("select date from tblcallcenter where username=@username and password=@password", sqlcon);
                cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtusername.Text);
                cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtpassword.Text);
                SqlDataAdapter sda2 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd3);
                DataTable dss = new DataTable();
                sda2.Fill(dss);
                String value2 = dss.Rows[0][0].ToString();
                DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(dss.Rows[0][0].ToString());

                Debug.WriteLine("value is :   " + value2);

                if (date.AddDays(90) < DateTime.Now)
                {
                    Changpass obj2 = new Changpass()/;
                    this.Hide();
                    obj2.Show();
                }
                else
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd4 = new SqlCommand("select user_id , username from tblcallcenter where username=@username and password=@password", sqlcon);
                    cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtusername.Text);
                    cmd4.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtpassword.Text);
                    SqlDataAdapter From_sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd4);
                    DataTable From_ds = new DataTable();
                    From_sda.Fill(From_ds);
                    String value1 = From_ds.Rows[0][1].ToString();
                    int id = int.Parse(From_ds.Rows[0][0].ToString());

                    Debug.WriteLine("value is :   " + value1);
                    Class1.Txtusername = txtusername.Text;
                    this.Hide();
                    SqlCommand cmd5 = new SqlCommand("select  [from], Take from tblcallcenter where username=@username and password=@password", sqlcon);
                    cmd5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", txtusername.Text);
                    cmd5.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtpassword.Text);
                    SqlDataAdapter sda1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd5);
                    DataTable ds = new DataTable();
                    sda1.Fill(ds);
                    Callcenter1 obj = new Callcenter1(ds.Rows[0][0].ToString(), ds.Rows[0][1].ToString());
                    this.Hide();
                    obj.Show();
                }
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Login try checking Useraname Or Password !", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid Login try checking Useraname Or Password !", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
```

Comment: Don't use `AddWithValue()`. Instead, use `cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.Nvarchar).Value = txtusername.Text;` -- Alter `SqlDbType.Nvarchar` to match whatever type you are using for that data within your database

Comment: @Symon that is all you can see in my code

Comment: This question should have been asked on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## 1. Don't forget the [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)

The responsibility of your form is only UI presentation. Should your form know how you store your data? Is your form responsible to know when user should change their password? No.

Each class should have one single responsibility. You could have an `AuthenticationService` class responsible to authenticate the user, and an `UserRepository` class to store/retrieve users in the database. For example this could be your button2 click handler:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var authenticationService = new AuthenticationService(sqlcon);


    try
    {
        var user = authenticationService.AuthenticateUser(txtusername.Text, txtpassword.Text);

        if (user.Date.AddDays(90) < DateTime.UtcNow)
        {
            Changpassad obj2 = new Changpassad();
            this.Hide();
            obj2.Show();

            return;
        }

        if (user.IsAdmin)
        {
            calladmin obj = new calladmin(user);
            this.Hide();
            obj.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            Callcenter1 obj = new Callcenter1(user);
            this.Hide();
            obj.Show();
        }

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid Login try checking Useraname Or Password !", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

You could take the principle even further and have your methods also have a single responsibility. For example, in the code above, I'd still extract the code checking if the passwords needs to be changed and the code responsible to open the correct form.

You already uses parameters in you SQL query. Good. You're resistant to [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Once you're familiar, I also recommend looking into ORMs like [Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/entity-framework) to facilitate the process.

---

## 2. Don't store plaintext password in database

Seriously. Never do that.

Always try to avoid managing users password. If you absolutely must, there are built-in classes in .Net framework to handle that. Here is some links, but a quick search should yield many more.

- [Quickstart: Add sign-in with Microsoft to an ASP.NET web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v1-aspnet-webapp)
- [Introduction to Identity on ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio)

If for some reasons you don't use theses and decide to manage password yourself. You need to find a cryptographically secure hashing algorithm ([not md5](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/19908/32288) like in the other answer). And you need to use an unique "salt" for each password you hash. I'll leave these link here since it's out of scope of your current question:

-[Hash passwords in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/consumer-apis/password-hashing?view=aspnetcore-2.2)
-[Difference between Encoding, Encryption and Hashing](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/295/encryption-and-decryption-in-asp-net-core)

---

## 3. Give significant name to your variable.

What is `button2`? What is `obj2`? What does `ds.Rows[0][0].ToString()` represent? You should try to give representative name to your variable. How about `btnLogin`, `callAdminForm`, ...

While we're here I recommend you read [C# General Naming Conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions). For example, naming convention for classes is PascalCase. It should be `CallAdmin` not `calladmin`.

---

## 4. Why do you have user/password stored in multiple tables?

Why are users stored in both `tbladmin` and `tblcallcenter`?

How about a single `tblUsers` and either a column or a related table specifying the user role? This will be easier to maintain in the long run. Why do something twice when you could do it once?

Answer (score 3):

You can care about:

1- Hashing the password using something like:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(32), HashBytes('MD5', 'password'), 2)
```

2- Compare exact letters case upper or lower.

```
Select * from tblcallcenter where password= @password COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

using case sensitive collation to be sure the password is same

3- You can use some new database c# technologies like Entity Framework or older like Typed Dataset or Linq to sql it's easy and quick to develop.
[Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/), [Typed Dataset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/typed-datasets), [Linq to SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/)

Comment: NO!!! Don't use MD5 hashing for passwords.  It's terribly insecure.  Use PBKDF2, bcrypt or scrypt.  -1 for being actively harmful information.

Answer (score 0):

It is not good idea to mix everything in one class. Try to split this task into several items:

1. validate user input (it could be separate method in same class)
2. separate class (or at least method) which handles DB. You should pass login information and get result (true/false is enough)
3. notification of result - display message about empty username/password, about incorrect login

Believe me, it would be more easily for you to develop it further. Good luck :)